# Python 3.7.4: inheriting both ABC and concrete class

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance, abc

I am modelling a game where each move is the throw of a bomb. There is 1 kind of regular bomb and 3 kinds of special bombs. So, I would like to create a class `SpecialBomb` that serves as an abstract base for those 3 special bomb classes. The idea is for `SpecialBomb` to inherit from `Bomb`, but still be unable to instantiate a `SpecialBomb` object. I tried the following:

```py
class Bomb:
    def __init__(self):
        self.boom = True

class SpecialBomb(Bomb, ABC):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

class CrossBomb(SpecialBomb):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

c = CrossBomb()
print(c.boom)
s = SpecialBomb()
```

The `boom` attribute was properly inherited in `c`, but the program **raised no error from the fact that I instantiated `SpecialBomb`. Is there something I am missing when I inherit `ABC`, or does this happen every time a class inherits both from `ABC` and a concrete class?**

Comment: ABC hasn't been defined. What is it?

Comment: @aerijman OP is referring to `ABC` from the `abc` module.

Comment: Instance attributes aren't inherited in the sense you are thinking. Also, an `ABC` by itself is perfectly instantiable, *provided* you haven't defined any abstract methods, which you haven't.

Comment: Also, `CrossBomb` is just as much an `ABC` as `SpecialBomb`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ABCMeta doesn't actually prevent you from instantiating a class unless it has an abstract method. You can wrap the `__init__` in SpecialBomb with the abstractmethod decorator to create the behavior you want.

```
from abc import abstractmethod, ABCMeta


class Bomb:
    def __init__(self):
        self.boom = True

class SpecialBomb(Bomb, metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @abstractmethod
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

class CrossBomb(SpecialBomb):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

c = CrossBomb()
print(c.boom)
s = SpecialBomb()
```